# A problem on an operator in inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $T \in L(V,W)$ . Define $T^* : W \to V$ by 
$$\langle T^*w,v\rangle = \langle w,Tv\rangle$$

is it true that $\dim \operatorname{Range}(T^*) = \dim \operatorname{Range}(T)$ ?

Here all the vector spaces are finite dimensional

Comment: Finite-dimensional spaces, or possibly infinite-dimensional?

Comment: finite dimensional

Comment: Hint: Range($T^{\ast}$) = Null($T$)$^{\perp}$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: done, thanks. But, this operator is not the usual $T^*$ i.e. adjoint operator. What is it ?

Comment: @user103623 : It is the usual adjoint operator. What is your definition of adjoint?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan : yes, it is the usual adjoint i.e $<Tv, w> =<v, T^*w>$ by complementing both sides. Is there any reason behind this ?

Comment: @user103623 None at all

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: Can you suggest some good book/resource which gives intuition behind all the operators ? I don't understand how I can predict the behaviour of the adjoint, self-adjoint, normal operator just from the definition.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11278/discussion-between-user103623-and-prahlad-vaidyanathan)